# Pandoc: [WARNING] Could not convert TeX math

Tags: pandoc, mathjax

I tried to convert html to docx by using Pandoc: 
here is my html code:

```
<p> Example: ${v_1} = {\rm{ }}{v_2}$</p>
```

with MathJax config in head:

```
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "TeX/AMSmath.js", "TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ["\(", "\)"]],
        displayMath: [['$$', '$$'], ["\[", "\]"]],
    },
    "HTML-CSS": {availableFonts: ["TeX"]}
});
```

Pandoc command that i used (Pandoc version 2.2.3.2):

```
    pandoc -s  test.html --mathjax  -f html+tex_math_dollars   --pdf-engine=xelatex  -o  xxx.docx
```

then i got a warning:

```
    [WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '{v_1} = {\rm{ }}{v_2}', rendering as TeX:
      {v_1} = {\rm{ }}{v_2}
                  ^
      unexpected "{"
      expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
```

Someone please tell me how to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the LaTeX `\textrm` instead of the plain tex `\rm`, and pandoc will be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Since 7k users have viewed this question since it was asked... perhaps others have made the same mistake I made as a novice RStudio user.

The first comment in both the `README.md` and the `README.Rmd` file is

```
<!-- README.md is generated from README.Rmd. Please edit that file -->
```

The intended meaning is (at least arguably) apparent if you pay sufficient attention to the this/that relative pronouns!

```
<!-- You should edit the README.Rmd file, not the README.md file -->
```

To repair the damage... I'm currently trying the suggestion to use an explicit `devtools::build_readme()` which I found  in [RStudio README.Rmd and README.md should be both staged use 'git commit --no-verify' to override this check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59775941/rstudio-readme-rmd-and-readme-md-should-be-both-staged-use-git-commit-no-veri)

No luck yet ... but I feel like I'm (finally!) making forward progress on getting $\sqrt{x}$ to display properly in my github README!